# How can I get the domain name of the request before using SSLEngine?

Tags: java, ssl, sslengine

I want to get the domain name in java before I determine which certificate I will use to send back.  How can I achieve that?

Do I need to analyze the bytes somehow myself? or is there a library for this?  or can some java SSL lib do it?

related post 
[Extract Server Name Indication (SNI) from TLS client hello](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832592/extract-server-name-indication-sni-from-tls-client-hello)

but I am hoping to just use java library to get the host name.

Comment: You don't need it before using the `SSLEngine,` you need it in your `KeyManager.getServerAliases()/chooseServerAlias()` methods.

Comment: @EJP ok?  so what method do I call when I receive the handshake message?  KeyManagerFactory.processClientHelloHandshake(byte[] data)?  I also see no methods on KeyManager here.... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?javax/net/ssl/KeyManager.html

Comment: It will call you, not the other way around. The engine will call the methods I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need it before using the `SSLEngine.` You need it in your custom `KeyManager` implementation, in the `chooseServerAlias()` method. You will need to discover the domain name by one of the techniques listed below, then create your `X509KeyManager` implementation, configured appropriately so as to return the appropriate keystore alias, then construct an `SSLContext,` initialize it with your `KeyManager`, then construct your `SSLEngine.` During the handshake the engine will call your key manager.

1. SNI. If the client supports SNI you can get the domain name from the initial `ClientHello` message as shown in your link. You will need to restore the `ByteBuffer` to its prior state after parsing it so that the `SSLEngine` can also parse it.
2. Otherwise you're relying on the IP addresses of each domain being different. You must already have a `SocketChannel,` so you already know the target address of the connection, i.e. the address the client used to connect to you, via `SocketChannel.getLocalAddress()`, so all you can do is map the domain name from that, if your domains have different IP addresses.

Answer (score 2):

Quite unexplicable, this is impossible to do directly with SSLEngine.

I came across the same problem myself and ended up writing a library ([TLS Channel](https://github.com/marianobarrios/tls-channel)). It does not do only that, it is actually a complete abstraction for SSLEngine, exposed as a ByteChannel. Regarding SNI, a function can be supplied to the server channel, to select SSLContexts depending on the supplied domain name.

Comment: There simply isn't anything that beats German engineers. This is absolutely fantastic! Thank you for making this available. I took the liberty to include your code for extracting SNIs in an edit suggestion.