# Streamreader format issue

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have created a UDP client and it works great.  The data is coming back in the correct format (verified through wireshark).  The problem is the format I  receive from streamreader is not what I expected.

Here is the code

```
private async void OnMessageReceived(DatagramSocket sender,     
 DatagramSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("message recv");
        var result = args.GetDataStream();

        var resultStream = result.AsStreamForRead(1024);
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(resultStream))
        {
            string text = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            Debug.WriteLine(text);
        }
    }
```

Here is the wireshark data

```
00 00 ff ff
```

Here is the text that is generated when I run my code

```
"?\0\u0002\0?\0\0d\0\0\u0001\u0001\0\0??"
```

I am assuming its a formatting issue.

Comment: Very unclear what you expect to get out of `00 00 ff ff` bytes as a string. Consider providing [MCVE] - inline data you receive as byte array and also show expected output along with what you get.

Comment: From your expected result it looks like your data is binary stream. Why StreamReader?

Comment: i want to see 00 00 ff ff as a string.  Thats my data

Comment: if not Streamreader, what should i use?

Comment: @user3363744: As a string... using what encoding? UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 would all interpret those 4 bytes differently (and there are many other encodings for string data).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this post: [Extract Server Name Indication (SNI) from TLS client hello](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832592/extract-server-name-indication-sni-from-tls-client-hello)

In particular:

- The host is utf8 encoded and readable when you utf8 enocde the
  buffer.
- Theres one byte before the host, that determines it's length.