# Explaining SSL ClientHello SNI message extension syntax defined by RFC6066 Server Name Indication

Tags: ssl, tls1.2, rfc, sni

[RFC6066](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6066#page-6) defines server name indication in extension of type `server_name`. The `extension_data` field of this extension SHALL contain `ServerNameList` where:

```
      struct {
          NameType name_type;
          select (name_type) {
              case host_name: HostName;
          } name;
      } ServerName;

      enum {
          host_name(0), (255)
      } NameType;

      opaque HostName<1..2^16-1>;

      struct {
          ServerName server_name_list<1..2^16-1>
      } ServerNameList;
```

Would be nice to have step by step explanation of this data structure. Also, here is the sample code, could be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#SNIExamples), how to read the extension data:

```
private static List<SNIServerName> exploreSNIExt(ByteBuffer input,
        int extLen) throws IOException {

    Map<Integer, SNIServerName> sniMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    int remains = extLen;
    if (extLen >= 2) {     // "server_name" extension in ClientHello
        int listLen = getInt16(input);     // length of server_name_list
        if (listLen == 0 || listLen + 2 != extLen) {
            throw new SSLProtocolException(
                    "Invalid server name indication extension");
        }

        remains -= 2;     // 0x02: the length field of server_name_list
        while (remains > 0) {
            int code = getInt8(input);      // name_type
            int snLen = getInt16(input);    // length field of server name
            if (snLen > remains) {
                throw new SSLProtocolException(
                        "Not enough data to fill declared vector size");
            }
            byte[] encoded = new byte[snLen];
            input.get(encoded);

            SNIServerName serverName;
            switch (code) {
                case StandardConstants.SNI_HOST_NAME: // 0x00
                    if (encoded.length == 0) {
                        throw new SSLProtocolException(
                                "Empty HostName in server name indication");
                    }
                    serverName = new SNIHostName(encoded);
                    break;
                default:
                    serverName = new UnknownServerName(code, encoded);
            }
            // check for duplicated server name type
            if (sniMap.put(serverName.getType(), serverName) != null) {
                throw new SSLProtocolException(
                        "Duplicated server name of type "
                        + serverName.getType());
            }

            remains -= encoded.length + 3;  // NameType: 1 byte
            // HostName length: 2 bytes
        }
    } else if (extLen == 0) {     // "server_name" extension in ServerHello
        throw new SSLProtocolException(
                "Not server name indication extension in client");
    }

    if (remains != 0) {
        throw new SSLProtocolException(
                "Invalid server name indication extension");
    }

    return Collections.<SNIServerName>unmodifiableList(
            new ArrayList<>(sniMap.values()));
}
```

Byte reader:

```
private static int getInt16(ByteBuffer input) {
    return ((input.get() & 0xFF) << 8) | (input.get() & 0xFF);
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21926971/2111085) is good example how data should be read. For example, extension type is defined by reading 2 bytes - so another question is - which RFC defines it?

Comment: *"Would be nice to have step by step explanation of this data structure"* - I consider this question as too broad. Instead of expecting an explanation of everything regarding this structure please explain first what you don't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have the source code implementing it, what is more needed to know?

The format used for the abstract schema is derived from [XDR](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4506) but is defined specifically in each TLS specification, like for the last one in [3.  Presentation Language](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-3)

So if we go piece by piece:

```
  struct {
      NameType name_type;
      select (name_type) {
          case host_name: HostName;
      } name;
  } ServerName;
```

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-3.6, this defines a structure:

- called "ServerName"
- whose first component is called `name_type` and is of type called `NameType` (defined later)
- whose second and last component is called `name` and is a variant (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-3.8): its value depends
  of the previous `name_type` content. If `name_type` have the value of
  `host_name`, then the value of this second component is of type
  `HostName` (defined later)

Next:

```
enum {
      host_name(0), (255)
} NameType;
```

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-3.5, this defines an enumeration with only one possible value (`0`), whose alias is `host_name`

The `(255)` is solely used to force the width (so 0 to 255 as values fits in one byte, this structure uses one byte of space), as explained in the specification:

> One may optionally specify a value without its associated tag to
> force the width definition without defining a superfluous element.

So it means on the wire you use 0, but if you have 0 it is to encode `host_name` in other parts of the specification.

```
  opaque HostName<1..2^16-1>;
```

In https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-3.2 we have:

> Single-byte entities containing uninterpreted data are of
> type opaque.

And in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-3.4, `<>` is used to define a variable length vector (or single dimensional array, or list).

So `HostName` is a vector containing between 1 to 2<sup>16</sup>-1 bytes (not elements), each element being of type "opaque", that is a single byte.

Note that there is further explanation as text in the RFC about SNI:

> "HostName" contains the fully qualified DNS hostname of the server,
> as understood by the client.  The hostname is represented as a byte
> string using ASCII encoding without a trailing dot.

```
  struct {
      ServerName server_name_list<1..2^16-1>
  } ServerNameList;
```

Same case as first one, but using a variable length array like above

- a `ServerNameList` is a structure
- whose only element is an array of variable length between 1 and 2<sup>16</sup>-1 bytes
- each element of this array being of type `ServerName`, as defined previously

Said differently:

- a `ServerNameList` structure is a list of elements, each one being of type `ServerName`
- this list can not be empty since it has at least a length of 1 byte
  (and up to 2<sup>16</sup>-1 bytes)
- a `ServerName` encodes a `name_type` (that can be only "host_name", aka value 0) and a name that is of type `HostName`, which is a non empty list of up to 2<sup>16</sup>-1 bytes encoding an hostname as explained in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6066#section-3

Comment: The TLS specification syntax is similar to XDR, but the encoding has significant differences. Instead see RFC 5246 4346 or 2246 section 4 or 8446 section 3.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks. I rewrote the answer using references from RFC8446.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek RFC6066 contains definition for `host_name(0)`, but there is no way for current TLS implementations to skip parsing `ServerName` structure whose `NameType != 0`, which may or may not be defined in future. Am I correct?

Comment: RFC6066 defines only host_name(0) so anything else is non conforming to RFC6066 and is "something else" than SNI. It is up to implementations then to define what to do but if they strictly follow the standard they should give an error when confronted with an unexpected structure.

Comment: @youfu you might be interested to read §2.2 of https://www.ietf.org/id/draft-iab-use-it-or-lose-it-00.txt and also https://mailarchive.ietf.org/arch/msg/tls/1t79gzNItZd71DwwoaqcQQ_4Yxc an email titled "[TLS] Accepting that other SNI name types will never work."

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thank you for pointing me to this email. This is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: The IAB document (first link) is now archived at https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-iab-use-it-or-lose-it-00.txt